# My canvas gets 2 borders instead of one

Tags: css, canvas

I have several canvases on my page. All of them should receive a thin border, except one, which should have a thick border. I want to put all the border information in the  element inside the HTML head. Here is my attempt:

```
<style>
/* The canvas with thick border has the id 'c' */
#c { border: 8px solid #8525AA; }
canvas { border: 2px solid #5408FA; }
</style>
```

This is an excerpt of my HTML body:

```
<canvas id="filler" width="10" height="70"></canvas>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="200">
</canvas>
<!-- more canvases follow here -->
```

Now the problem: With this code, the canvas with id 'c' gets TWO borders, a thick one and a thin one! Is this intended behaviour? If yes, how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: which browser have you tested this on?

Comment: It's theoretically impossible for an element to have two borders, so this may be a bug in the particular browser version you're testing in. Have you tried other browsers? None of the browsers I've tested have the problem. (Under Windows, all of them.)

Comment: I have tested only on Mac OSX 10.4, but with various browsers (SeaMonkey 2.0, Opera 10.6, Safari 4). All of them show the double-border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Shame on me!

I'll document what was going on, and what mistake I did.

I violated the old rule that, when narrowing down a problem, I should really remove EVERY piece of code which is not necessary to describe my problem. In my case, there were two lines left in my HTML file, which I thought that they could not possibly affect my issue (and hence I did not post these lines here). Well, I was bitten this time:

My HTML file had in the header also the following line:

```
<script src="fabric_custom1.js"></script>
```

This loads a subset of [fabrik.js](http://fabricjs.com/), a JavaScript library which makes handling of Canvases easier. This by itself doesn't do anything bad. However, in my body I also had the line

```
<script>var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');</script>
```

This creates an object of type fabric.Canvas, which provides an interface for manipulating the canvas which was defined earlier by the id 'c'. Since I don't do anything with this object yet, I thought this statement should not harm, and I didn't bother removing it.

However it turns out, that this statement draws the second border of the Canvas. I guess this is a bug in Fabric.js.

Sorry for having bothered all of you...

**UPDATE:**

I just learned that the double-border is not a bug in fabric.js, but a feature - it is designed to behave this way. In order to avoid it, one has to create a fabric.StaticCanvas instead of a fabric.Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your CSS like this:

```
<style>
/* The canvas with thick border has the id 'c' */
canvas { border: 2px solid #5408FA; }
#c { border: 8px solid #8525AA; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your going to have multiple canvas and only be using them once then just add the properties as you use the canvas like this,

```
<canvas id="1" 
            style="border:2px solid #5408FA"
            width="10px" 
            height="70px">

</canvas>  

<canvas id="2" 
            style="border:8px solid #8525AA"
            width="400px" 
            height="200px">

</canvas>
```

If your going to use the same properties multiple times then you can just set the properties to #canvas

BUT!

Canvases have two sizes - the actual pixel grid size (in the width and height attributes) and the CSS size.

If the pixel size is not specified it typically defaults to something like 300x300.

The CSS size only specifies the amount of space taken in the page, and defaults to the pixel size. If they are not equal the image will be scaled.

You MUST specify the pixel size in the  element, or set it using Javascript: